# Copy-paste from Excel to PowerPoint via VBA: Align two pictures

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm using VBA to copy-paste ranges from Excel into PowerPoint. I have three Excel sheets from which I copy two different things: the data and the annotations. On the PowerPoint slides, data and annotations are supposed to be next to each other, data on the left, annotations on the right. However, these sections are of different sizes. I have no problem putting the data on the slides with the help of a for each loop, but how do I get the annotations to fit snugly to the right of the data?

Right now I have three sections of very similar code for the three different sheets because I don't know how to align data and annotations without manually defining `myShape.Top` and `myShape.Left`for annoations. Is there a way to tell PowerPoint "Put this picture next to the other picture?"

Comment: What if you set `RightHandShape.Left` to `LeftHandShape.Left + LeftHandShape.Width` etc.

Comment: The idea is great, thank you! It doesn't quite work as intended as it's way too far right (solved by adding -200) and the third picture is for some reason even further right, but it gives me something to work with. I'm gonna google about shape.width and see if there are known problems and/or workarounds.